# if string inside index, error not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def dict_trunkated(collection, df):
    dict_all = {}
    #STEP 1:   DICT_ALL anlegen mit keys
    for element in collection: 
        dict_all[element] = {"id_ja" : None, "id_nein" : None ,"ZUW_ja": {}, "ZUW_nein": {}}

    for row in range(len(df)):
        if "_Ja" in row: #error: argument type of int is not iterable
            dict_all[row[6][0:-3]]["id_ja"] = row[5]
            dict_all[row[6][0:-3]]["ZUW_ja"].append(row[1])
        if "_Nein" in row: #same error will be here
            dict_all[row[6][0:-3]]["id_nein"] = row[5]
            dict_all[row[6][0:-3]]["ZUW_nein"].append(row[1])

    return dict_all
```

Don't know how to make it iterable.. 
Was thinking with

```
row[6]
```

but did not work..

Comment: `for row in range(len(df)):` will yield one `int` object at a time. So what do you mean by `if "_Ja" in row:` where `row` is an `int` object.

Comment: I would like to find a string with this ending, find the stemmed string in my dict and add all the necassary values i need to my dict

Comment: @Yannisch In your code row will become an index value which is nothing but int object.

Comment: @Yannisch Could you please provide what data we have inside df ?

Comment: I changed the loop to `for row in df:`

But then I receive a KeyError: ' '

Answer (score 2):

`for row in range(len(df)):`

In this case row is a number. For example `range(3) = [0, 1, 2]`
And you iterate by this numbers.

If you want iterate by df items you should do:

`for row in df:`

Comment: try print `row` i you for loop and look what is wrong with you code